# How do I encode RSA keys written in my own Java implementation in ASN.1 DER format?

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, asn.1, der

I am writing my own implementation of RSA in Java, without using the built-in Key interface. I have read in PKCS #1 that the standard way of encoding RSA keys is using ASN.1 in DER format. However, I am not certain how to do this with my own version of RSA. This is just a program for encrypting and decrypting files and text, for personal purposes only. I don't necessarily want to create X.509 certificates. I just want to write the encoded string to a .txt file. I I figure that I should use Bouncy Castle somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Bouncy Castle for this.

1. Download the Bouncy Castle lightweight API source code and compile;
2. Create an RSA key pair (using the Bouncy Castle API);
3. Retrieve the "encoded" version by stepping through the ASN.1 code.

There have been books (and tutorials) written about encoding in ASN.1, this is not something that can be easily answered on StackOverflow. I suppose you want to read a few of those and possibly get your hands on the ISO/IEC 8859 specifications.

Furthermore you'd need the PKCS#1 standard, the X.509 standard (for SubjectPublicKeyInfo) and PKCS#8 to encode the internal structure of the private key.